# How to make one slider/widget update multiple plots in Bokeh/Python/Pywidgets?

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, ipywidgets

Using Jupyter notebook, **how to have one slider interactively update two independent functions in two figures?**
There is a link to a similar question without answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43963402/how-to-change-multiple-interactive-plots-with-a-single-input-in-python).

Using Bokeh [Javascript Callback slider power example](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html), I tried adding a second set of variables x and y but keep using the same callback. The graphs do  not update anymore.
Any suggestions? I also was trying to do the same with Pywidget but did not get anywhere. I would prefer using IPywidget if there is a solution there.
The end goal is to have a dashboard with an input composed of multiple slider, and an output composed of multiple plots all dependent on the same set of sliders input.

```
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_notebook, show

output_notebook()

x = [x*0.005 for x in range(0, 200)]
y = x
x1 = [x1*0.005 for x1 in range(0, 200)]
y1 = x1

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y))
source1 = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x1=x1,y1=y1))

plot = Figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot.line('x', 'y', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

plot1 = Figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
plot1.line('x1', 'y1', source=source1, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, source1=source1), code="""
    var data = source.data;
    var data1 = source1.data;
    var f1 =cb_obj.value
    var f = cb_obj.value
    x = data['x']
    y = data['y']
    x1 = data['x1']
    y1 = data['y1']

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        y[i] = Math.pow(x[i], f)
    }
    for (i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
        y1[i] = Math.pow(x1[i], f1)
    }
    source.change.emit();
    source1.change.emit();
""")

slider = Slider(start=0.1, end=4, value=1, step=.1, title="power")
slider.js_on_change('value', callback)

layout = column(slider, plot,plot1)

show(layout)
```

A snapshot of the two graphs with the slider is shown below. Slider is not updating any graph.
[Slider and two plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poKMB.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just a slight fix:

replace

```
x1 = data['x1']
y1 = data['y1']
```

with

```
x1 = data1['x1']
y1 = data1['y1']
```

Apart from that, your example works great, thank you! I hope other people will find it useful.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Now trying to do multiple slider control multiple plots in Bokeh, will post another question if needed.  Do you know how we can achieve the same results in Ipywidget?

Comment: @AliTarraf It would be great if you marked the answer as accepted if it helped you. Regarding Ipywidget - sorry, I've never used it.